# Barcode128A in Delphi FastReport

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, fastreport

We generate barcodes with BarOne (zebra printer program) in Code128A Standard without any problem.
When we try to print barcodes with `fastreport` the length of the barcode not what I want it to be.
The limitation seems to be the label size.

Does QuickReport or Fastreport have a new component to generate barcode?

Answer (score 0):

The data of the Barcode are only numbers? If so, Zebra printer is automatically changing the type of the barcode to Code128C which is narrower but only print pairs of numbers. The problem is that FastReport only prints in Code128A.

We had the same behaviour with Toshiba TEC printers, they change the type in-line, A>C>A as needed. But the solution in FastReport was to print a label with a Barcode 128 font; there are a bunch on Internet.